# How can I convert A Chrome Extension to A Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with no UI. It has content scripts. Is there a way to convert this Chrome extension into a Chrome App? I know that there are many differences between them. But, for example, can a Chrome App load a Chrome extension that is stored in a local directory on the user's local computer?

Thanks

Comment: i don't think apps can use extensions. however, you MIGHT be able to use (read: load+apply) the extension's JS code within the app, but it's not going to automatic by any means, and you will probably have to mockup certain expectations that the extension makes.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a Chrome extension with no UI. It has content scripts. Is there a way to convert this Chrome extension into a Chrome App?

No, since a Chrome App can't interact with the browser content, so no content scripts.

You *could* in theory create [a browser inside a Chrome app](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) and inject your scripts there, but that would be a jarring experience, since your pseudo-browser wouldn't have access to the main cookie store, passwords and such, as well as some of the browser UI will have to be implemented by you.

> Can a Chrome App load a Chrome extension that is stored in a local directory on the user's local computer?

No, neither an app nor an extension can install another app/extension.

If an extension is already installed, an app can send it a message and vice versa using `onMessageExternal`, enabling an extension and an app to work together; however, it's up to the user to install both.